# Scrapy infinite scroll without pagination urls

Tags: scrapy, infinite-scroll

Using Scrapy , Failed to scrap books title authors and links from infinite scroll bookstore [www.aseeralkotb.com](https://www.aseeralkotb.com/categories/%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9) website,  from devtools inspect, can't find links for next pages.The code

```
import scrapy


class booksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'books'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.aseeralkotb.com/categories/%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9',
    ]
   
    def parse(self, response):
        for book in response.css('div.flex.flex-col.items-center'):
            yield {
                 'title': book.css('a:not([itemprop="author"])::attr(title)').get(), 
                 'author': book.css('h5[itemprop=name]::text').get(), 
                  'detailslinks': book.css('a[title]::attr(href)').re(r'.*books.*')
         
            }
        
        for link in  book:
            yield response.follow(link.get(),method='POST',callback = self.parse_links)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The website is sending `Ajax` request and response from API is json along with html. With scrapy, it's throwing response status 419 but with powerful `requests` module it's working.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

session = requests.Session()
req_homepage = session.get('https://www.aseeralkotb.com/categories/%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9')
soup_homepage = bs(req_homepage.content, "lxml")

for meta in soup_homepage.find_all('meta'):
    if meta.get('name', None) == 'csrf-token':
        token = meta['content']

data = {"fingerprint":{"id":"UejQB7Z1XFiSDQ3fb05D","name":"categories.books.index","locale":"ar","path":"categories/%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9","method":"GET","v":"acj"},"serverMemo":{"children":{"product-purchase-UtqTb6t0gxWEo6ym20401":{"id":"ZyeTxCh4kmoo4uVFdgAL","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-qfh1S6g5Hqr2yK5p19255":{"id":"IKQCqiaMPBOUz2y9pulb","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-kcsVg5TIGPUm7uBX19253":{"id":"6IV59cn7CyPi4ZlGRSTZ","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-dpgMlpItsMT6QvBC18496":{"id":"G0FV4of9IwUwxN2n3orA","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-djH1nx7Dd1CqjN1Y18245":{"id":"YQY9oXuI80F9zJFUdypB","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-HlsxJBgDCurMZMJ718218":{"id":"lFR46ttmPcJLyBmsPR9t","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-iYHhJD8zFwVpmpV417621":{"id":"dwfj7y3wUh9GMZVVwvM7","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-yEBL5qWdHGmE0cdD17348":{"id":"DwEuSTw1Z2iOcvLsG1dR","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-knjkw2Oa8EncjoPh17074":{"id":"SwZE2176HaD1T0pxPdXI","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-Ce7TBXAPYZbgxvyG17068":{"id":"6UeQ1JImg9AbcI2MjEIv","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-yvOJtFHoJb4M6UxD16469":{"id":"roh9C9Z1U3LVdLsdoRPg","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-zwXX0znXxyZh1ChE16452":{"id":"aQW3CPDhlstTNhRZE5rF","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-YjWk9AseS4bFmf0A16451":{"id":"nhwCNKGwVYa1oBF4wZQF","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-f4jgVxc9M3UPULFQ16010":{"id":"agM3tBl7u3DujVagMkQf","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-kUIj358Zh59HVPtI15963":{"id":"ETXtvZi87WrByYRjpmXu","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-Fg1GaFl9Pntx4JZ115740":{"id":"6PR3Jkr5DVm5QfFWBlCa","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-PenVRhRXZxC7IC8b15511":{"id":"DNRe2AZjqoyTOB1A6sDb","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-pLaYFiLzVJb4M83j15409":{"id":"4Qd9qRflfMzAZIloUHld","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-w59GJbmTvLOlzMzb14799":{"id":"kBl8JNOxnsveu7FeHQQy","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-6DwBE3WETIFYKhdN12394":{"id":"SFfx5sZFVFM1f5KgH9Mn","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-f0U27L0WdrCmdqlN10180":{"id":"LgNzK1XCeJByevDb6poq","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-src1a3URLG9nJHaL10178":{"id":"Zi1ebeCyIrCtqRccwA53","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-EgUvPZAnQvWaYNW69259":{"id":"ziL2dLDBmFMuO4gDHXMo","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-ScLkhiY9GDAIx9Q08620":{"id":"jeQ8oGEJUr3PO0USYTpq","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-33v00TdKKU73hhy38041":{"id":"bBr4JLNXg1uX5iSZf8hj","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-LT345WWsWMGIvPuP7888":{"id":"3B4WCJ59UTTvTKqir9TG","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-rjL4YnQBMXTQNKfW6800":{"id":"4JIdTHJUB6xtOHmeaShS","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-mOsgHazcWpZkkVuj6769":{"id":"fP49Yqnm2jPIkyOdALce","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-xEdrRToHrJJaLnd56733":{"id":"DsVrI5clO75rbmndtcQh","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-d7lOpqgD8t1wJkln6505":{"id":"qBk8BN2BtperIcxGKEyz","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-EipwbWTn9Jeli9mD6492":{"id":"smxCuFfMttSiDhivuhVx","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-gYZcbi026JAJ2rI76482":{"id":"dLVtuM3kp2xQoUaUivW2","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-vcr70vd4N4GhmX3v5598":{"id":"FXohQdm6DsAsfiA7ky8D","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-ndg0avUkJyeaAjxr5597":{"id":"fPj75X6MGP1F9B8wCnbh","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-mmDxYaLyNp7tf1Ur5596":{"id":"vOyPfgp0xSDRDocvSkck","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-EJx6fHwdkQfs5HsV5464":{"id":"0Fwp6t0CvMWW4DKXrvl1","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-QqsQdaRZfLix4SFv5390":{"id":"GvHb7qpXU3ZbyT23IyCa","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-myb9iuvqnWPyZ9ZS5288":{"id":"CeO7EKkMVzLwCs2a4B8b","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-QLEcTNKMgEzLwj474399":{"id":"e8s5FCAzdjp3v2n2S17w","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-33APh2rbpMr3CoLw4366":{"id":"6IncxfWnql9Ry3iKh50K","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-J6G2R5WjaANyoBvO3802":{"id":"DPspcwFWY0YsXBhNylDK","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-FNULLNL7NsfDL2iU3372":{"id":"itmEuicd6tSGTYfyeT92","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-aKfSCnbU75ingBoz3369":{"id":"OqY8jDBJfFZPb3PF6WF3","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-Hzkxb8cQW839i1BF3358":{"id":"Hww5WUf3yF7cl64FpSrU","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-yYiQW4FoZVQaIj0f3347":{"id":"wkidC4ZjSFpD4S3znzWp","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-EUSO3tzNJWz82pro3339":{"id":"40i3nSqkXeoxqiHSeory","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-8p7VIhbPdlhdu7Vv3338":{"id":"ndAIGfRABihmt0u7IT0T","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-hx28ANKENTuaVKpf3336":{"id":"yrkVeL3pR4IYkygrhdu8","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-MFdCqZvvHPrO5wUF2596":{"id":"y9C5kpMtxN4Dvstjgmlf","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-ZuVNZD15YHAjyeXZ2312":{"id":"gGvw2omCzLl3hk1s4Gab","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-rRIesRZpv9DwUc4l2270":{"id":"GNnC209aFE4basog52gW","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-Uxcb1TGqlJ0qsl422263":{"id":"WYCC1IkMz4CFZXPhuoJv","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-MPxl1tSpOr1gFK132257":{"id":"TVMlPCpaRgOnKBF7E8at","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-TKUDRMQ5LQr2vPOH2256":{"id":"Z1SYSyBBJcJ5xDRJIq3K","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-clf0iKNNxbF3RP8S2246":{"id":"7L8LgAOrczfS5AEdR3Qk","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-Xm3U4jdGlnAqvyoL1068":{"id":"9JG1ldDPPSXooHAajlFx","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-eMpapFY3p5ovgN041011":{"id":"Q6qvzqqp3iRs20ddgEz2","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-MT0TvvJugLIPYoty733":{"id":"cdIo3ldJVSq5YhMnntK2","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-MiBlkeqoVQxZBm5T709":{"id":"lY0m5u5Utv1fApfe9gkU","tag":"div"},"product-purchase-00S4TJP3KwpW2LGE163":{"id":"aPrcqxInNQvTwxP0VXl3","tag":"div"},"product-subscribe-yRzy0FkZdLWdo7XR20773":{"id":"VmbEwrO7kHes9PKxocZB","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-1mWTBfEM7P467JGk20758":{"id":"WQd4NZaN33sFWLwf5K1n","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-r6WSTnxHwvXFvBwT20751":{"id":"4IDg4SjaZZ5IVMXIZLvj","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-eIoK1MoaJpqxYnE820738":{"id":"VhDO4mLwF6VuBnxVQeud","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-ocj4Dg5pkeMF6dlc20514":{"id":"jIpA3NgdMt5mKOrfUFBY","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-5vQrM5G6bRWr3sdF20309":{"id":"WPin6VpzPMSTYJnHVHnc","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-3dtA2RrYwf6eyjQJ18758":{"id":"vJyb3HjOHnjtd46eVBDd","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-Zm9XK65Bs5hh3FnM18564":{"id":"8pztwlfBC2rtEJWdlCaq","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-XTolx99rODPjIgtv16986":{"id":"dwheNGnH965gp9WDKsOr","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-l2VIqWTmf87ZgqtD16828":{"id":"9DLlD5UFuZxxWwz2jsbO","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-zYBxqCjwnKDu3yMp15939":{"id":"uL9sPDEdiG2r9oOzyIYQ","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-sLigK9XqznyCgecf15829":{"id":"gT4u0yu2VQ1qvJDKcYLV","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-GbUoDex2mywBdcFj15817":{"id":"SHrtQLBimqKUdi2OoRcH","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-JlN9RokXNnQLOdGe15784":{"id":"PYkTYi4jGUllClA2DhJb","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-gPjML6fVlHyUj2Ii15763":{"id":"ZE4K9qaU0zTJQUFgcEBX","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-sJ6a8Ol57MjVr1VS15746":{"id":"D1oct0mExCsYlfnLpT3Y","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-ei8K00jzGzyw0OAx15340":{"id":"moj8AU8ITJzjNNw3G4A3","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-L6oPtzwTcOWK1lx315140":{"id":"YgYJ8QcMjJpMvEsYHIMy","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-Lm7CewNrWqGydq5O15131":{"id":"8za2SqoS5df7rhR7OAzw","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-GYsBLhYUgYKqSWPJ15113":{"id":"1oV4nPzGpO6yjWw3yv4W","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-GZKGeEu4f4dvL2mf15112":{"id":"xLeCbMlKgU9bK7p30mMs","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-aR6LZDzdIjscTZ6915111":{"id":"x8e9qCpRYIMfX9sYtWTv","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-XpXcVBMlQes7SWZD15110":{"id":"ZwM81qTpWoz4o2SJrurN","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-sL1akvAsI0L9M6Sp15109":{"id":"qerkCyPGdTqI50nfJVoQ","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-ZFL5h89noWths4Pw15108":{"id":"FHELi6vbygpbXj7Bz5hH","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-1rUWoausOxjfJvxe15103":{"id":"6bZbg6z4Rdwc44IPSIml","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-R5LPt0IzebR9CToS15102":{"id":"UBBJDrcglaDdOodkzIw6","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-4wFgoWyjcyKK99sn15101":{"id":"Jcus3pKf5XRMhJjYlDbh","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-ZKIySkqwWyJRUGSs15100":{"id":"NnRRovqaJBxufzpmnCMT","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-yvTcT83IDrNlTWVh15075":{"id":"oTGJT5zdZhirdTBUhlwv","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-jYkAw18TU2kKucyX15074":{"id":"1NjVteiNou2cqsZlrEPf","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-v6s8a3Ly9FG43W3A15073":{"id":"QWR927Zsuqg84db2KruG","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-k5TBn2yPgSrstwLZ15072":{"id":"bi7leKZWdvnuUkMilp4J","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-6T365pFVLQdMVmDZ15060":{"id":"LfuUmRRA2js9GoC0L2Nx","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-ZHQGi0hxGzAHJ39A15059":{"id":"ZemHtbGEerLcoitho0RD","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-HE50lRzpS5AgStYb15057":{"id":"6M2Rka0WINDr4PYGZZ3M","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-bT35k73z60Ed9yY915045":{"id":"3uQt7GU9Uo3tyORYAMil","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-SPO0MvNJuabC6NAp15043":{"id":"0m8r2tEPDoIyAtBYjzWV","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-WvCz6mOPZZMLDMKP15042":{"id":"rfngJqbQp6DsQKX62m3g","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-vSvxWf8pytHJN9pp15041":{"id":"zpsSYqJuKaf7lyXGvCVL","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-HvUSSwU9aLtdwERi15026":{"id":"65bRSZdGU2BiXvOPvK1M","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-JoBhsEYknTwCNQO615025":{"id":"nGLJb3g4dfgFyLG1E2RP","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-UmEYlSKPPsPycaVX15024":{"id":"LKo35Zluk4e0Koj68rPq","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-UsvB6PTbFfAoI9hx15023":{"id":"lC4lOpZw4Lh9MPt2qpkP","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-I1WyE6ufwQ9G1Ft515022":{"id":"x0JDVCXur1mMgF8dIt3w","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-y7y2MxFlWFUbAMbM15021":{"id":"k87Sszv2eGTeTsPUiBzh","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-FlzEb2POwkiguiUI15020":{"id":"BLGlCiJ1szZrlHpiP7ZQ","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-g4vTMLyzwuIkVadn15019":{"id":"ciCtorj47jS3d8wUFejC","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-QQeLYvJ8VFxEEntJ15017":{"id":"mzFB1B82fUE9kUv8WEl8","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-ikCVKwzLPe1u7b5w15016":{"id":"cfxQ1ZWKs0wKx2yMF5bK","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-N6NxXqB6HFevy1nz15014":{"id":"z4URc41Su7sUgWvteelw","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-ueCdo719n5SvnyfP15012":{"id":"Ht7GXRGEG4hkUmiHt84A","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-qpmviK0UvlJcHEqG15011":{"id":"CJwyMYE2bXbbQOBsEnYk","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-85Ua7zLrK9AleFjK14954":{"id":"ML4Vb5woaOYnShZ9dqQO","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-PKq65IoGJ1PyUD1x14953":{"id":"mt01jkD5c4DFpMfA4NGk","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-FtAxVQtqbs8TaYoL14951":{"id":"FZhNs0Q21dVZLpYuQlDW","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-JhA1CePxtb24Gvju14948":{"id":"SbI5buYEza9VHqelZe0y","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-yeLjGuGtngHDYKwX14947":{"id":"PnQm4Xbmn4AmaLOa6G5p","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-2bxzRKWUCmiI6eQg14946":{"id":"1rD5hutK5sLOBEaRzNLT","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-50LpKJCiZTPNWgJ514945":{"id":"5A4zs9nn5eAUq4NsR70x","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-tM9jf0BsgwsEG9hT14911":{"id":"hN9yFkEBUzYpC2nz7jgn","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-7deI0GyTIbfVOcBS14895":{"id":"y8uTAVS65X0EBcvVr641","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-fypkinhPWy81wlfa14894":{"id":"lMPYeNQzt2iW2ivOGnmB","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-mXxG0vTN164c35jF14893":{"id":"Ep4UtICtRAlwcfh2Emtu","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-S0oDv6N93Xk9bPdi14892":{"id":"7mWdOLHM4BkLq9gyKOaY","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-05ZfIFm0Cnhl7Imb14891":{"id":"0Bci5ghDP3QlwJSf0KaV","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-Gp3WyclRaYbn36dD14890":{"id":"f9D3tYyGHZoAu5NJXHdG","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-KLVrzBEsYviELaSj14889":{"id":"0ZbBEfGBcumwHNp7ZLNO","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-X02QnUbn3xudmZ1L14888":{"id":"hVou04c0KJRqKsOSbJdN","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-yXla3oPVDYN3Vur214887":{"id":"PSDR4KT6JyIUbpzMRPno","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-5jNhetoC9Bk1XyPS14846":{"id":"y7iTY5Ev4WtKdzQuxfrf","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-jdyOsUDtLILYi3in14845":{"id":"dN9jQJxzoHBS3xbGgaHV","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-gXry0Ckk4R3BT33I14844":{"id":"S2XMx6bmPsL8sFhZ2xSm","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-GQLIe2jHz8qlm1wz14843":{"id":"yPv6y9kFCze7AablsZJB","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-sOSj4GOn3b71eEYr14842":{"id":"7ykiDhZjNZnwRnj2ylL7","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-jKRg5V6Pc8iFcEzQ14841":{"id":"WD98LMGnvF5u84SvsZys","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-31PEcO75pIcROBQU14840":{"id":"R4ww7PhUfIWlAUwxsT7O","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-HJyjOq2tikd2FSK614798":{"id":"aqBbbagDahKCsyrf5jGj","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-218PhgawNrm1JELd14797":{"id":"OkjW50DWfvwrYu8gyald","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-wzaEfWMwGxJoOY2u14796":{"id":"m5HbgsQ6Vz8z1kY4F1XD","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-TUqdfeOJEl1kzzOT14795":{"id":"3kK0p9Enf6wjmm42ffLU","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-NVVYbYS3DrjYDnbF14774":{"id":"G2umaj0vz2sKUzIOwPRh","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-PomMwfXUqs2IOtIm14762":{"id":"uN6NNaD6b1U9sjNto7dN","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-c5EPhrLOMTlZ7Tuv14761":{"id":"QeHeSZVtyNuu9zNRyzmu","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-BG6RUC1AATxL2G6014725":{"id":"kzm8VCfne3XwJeaSXAmt","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-0gaBCnnSQvwbkS9G14707":{"id":"ZinqyAtnd8T43iEaG929","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-AVfjo8KFcEkACtTX14701":{"id":"CtqyeablMWYjAZz4MQpq","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-1c5PbFKkfGWTys6614700":{"id":"mD69zoMCK433XBWBNio5","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-qWn2qbh0IKfNpfsk14699":{"id":"xdHvh84rQO70o4yflUzA","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-tFnnvaMXN4MyxZtW14698":{"id":"UGRUo17rWYSFwAfRrw3M","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-BROlVfnoMtJk8W4j14697":{"id":"Zc8raAUZh0K0f7N4c8NW","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-Mp7DAJ9pmRuD9yPF14696":{"id":"xedSCruQosmIA15bJj3M","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-iN5lKARgJWKwEDPJ14695":{"id":"qjuiypEF50E8mLFFqhlK","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-nMz8C6x9pQPAzt3y14694":{"id":"7bfRDQJYQQn9dPy4xDqa","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-YmO2AddjHOkAaQbk14481":{"id":"eWoVovbjGifEq4xZOmut","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-Hf03N2WnGVoO542X14479":{"id":"JWl7ZWMFcGdpQAp6JWPO","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-W4zRXjcSq8S1Q26314393":{"id":"THVgQqBm81pt9yTuSdzr","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-x4q89iHlGfzFaHDF14346":{"id":"Bs3GDYjKvPKIDX0EiSaQ","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-2pauKbKqsWPgd6T814345":{"id":"xOkvQkc0xysanYfmOiVq","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-YmW8kp91gpaTzrOS14318":{"id":"Bl6uZEgfzGTGEOSqNdTG","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-oJJi3QSe1oKjIXyJ14288":{"id":"hLa5WGH6HX8viaInx4nA","tag":"a"},"product-subscribe-sILG315q7DgNmWJH14275":{"id":"0QjBeKzvv5U0cYgk2M0i","tag":"a"}},"errors":[],"htmlHash":"87fc3f9f","data":{"books":[],"perPage":6,"page":27,"category":[],"ids":[14]},"dataMeta":{"modelCollections":{"books":{"class":"App\\Models\\Book","id":["20401","19255","19253","18496","18245","18218","17621","17348","17074","17068","16469","16452","16451","16010","15963","15740","15511","15409","14799","12394","10180","10178","9259","8620","8041","7888","6800","6769","6733","6505","6492","6482","5598","5597","5596","5464","5390","5288","4399","4366","3802","3372","3369","3358","3347","3339","3338","3336","2596","2312","2270","2263","2257","2256","2246","1068","1011","733","709","163","20773","20758","20751","20738","20514","20309","18758","18564","16986","16828","15939","15829","15817","15784","15763","15746","15340","15140","15131","15113","15112","15111","15110","15109","15108","15103","15102","15101","15100","15075","15074","15073","15072","15060","15059","15057","15045","15043","15042","15041","15026","15025","15024","15023","15022","15021","15020","15019","15017","15016","15014","15012","15011","14954","14953","14951","14948","14947","14946","14945","14911","14895","14894","14893","14892","14891","14890","14889","14888","14887","14846","14845","14844","14843","14842","14841","14840","14798","14797","14796","14795","14774","14762","14761","14725","14707","14701","14700","14699","14698","14697","14696","14695","14694","14481","14479","14393","14346","14345","14318","14288","14275"],"relations":["series","publisher","authors","authors.media","discountOffer","media","subscribers"],"connection":"mysql"}},"models":{"category":{"class":"App\\Models\\Category","id":"سياسة","relations":["children"],"connection":"mysql"}}},"checksum":"a978b9f9cb184baf2016d28758b9f4efa7faf13cadc95f1a53d44903ac4ce7ca"},"updates":[{"type":"callMethod","payload":{"id":"2a5n","method":"loadMore","params":[]}}]}
    
  

headers = {
    "content-type":"application/json",
    "x-csrf-token": token,
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "x-livewire": "true"
            
        }


req = session.post('https://www.aseeralkotb.com/livewire/message/categories.books.index', json=data, headers=headers).json()


json_content = req['effects']['html']
soup = bs(json_content, "lxml")
#print(soup)


for card in soup.select('div[class="flex"]'):
    name = card.select_one('div.flex.flex-col.items-center > a > h1').text
    print(name)
```

**Output:**

```
سياسات تقنين الشريعة
بعد الليبرالية        
الاعلان الاسلامي      
في قلب الأحداث        
الدولة والثورة        
أحاديث فى آسيا        
العالم عام 2050       
حرب المائة عام على ف..
تاريخ العصامية والجر..
البرجوازية المصرية و..
الدبلوماسية الإقتصاد..
عدني يا أبي - عام من..
عولمة - لا حرب حضارا..
الإستياء العالمي - ح..
العبودية مقابل الامن..
أيام مرسي
11 يوما مات بعدها جم..
33 استراتيجية للحرب   
المختطفات : شهادات م..
روسيا الأوراسية كقوة..
ملفات السويس
سنوات الغليان
اختلال العالم
الماسونية
خرافة التقدم والتأخر
نحن شعب مهذب - تأملا..
خوف
كل يوم هو اضافة
هرطقات 2: عن العلمان..
الحصار
الجورنالجي وكاتم الا..
أميركا والقوى الصاعد..
مقدمة قصيرة عن الحرب..
مقدمة قصيرة عن الثور..
مقدمة قصيرة عن الثور..
القاهرة - موسكو
قصة سقوط صدام حسين
فن الحرب
الحروب الميسرة
أسرار حرب الغاز
اليوتوبية: مقدمة قصي..
الحياة السرية لصدام..
موسوليني - أسطورة لا..
الأسرار الكبرى للماس..
أسرار وحقيقة الماسون..
أحجار على رقعة الشطر..
يأجوج ومأجوج- من الو..
الشيطان أمير هذا الع..
غزة في أزمة - تأملات..
كل جيش الكرملين ( مو..
أخيل جريحا  ( إرث جم..
ماذا حدث للمصريين؟
العلمانية الجزئية وا..
العلمانية الجزئية وا..
عودة الوعى
موسوليني وهتلر : قصة..
الثورة الدائمة
نار وغضب - البيت الأ..
حلقات زحل
كفاحي
لعبة الأمم
آليات المؤامرة الكون..
‎استنساخ الفشل التار..
عمالقة الفن الاسود
الرقابة و التعتيم فى..
الاختراق الصهيونى لل..
جند الخلافة
محكمة حقوق الإنسان ا..
مذكرات هيرمان بلاك
الجيش الأمريكى فى حر..
روح الشرائع
خنجر إيران
المتآمرون على الأمة
الثورة العميقة رحلة..
جمهورية الضحك الأولي
عالم بدون اسرائيل
المقاصد الشرعية في ا..
الحروب الامريكية الج..
معجم المصطلحات السيا..
حقوق عربية ضائعة .....
من الشاه الى نجاد....
العلاقات المصرية الخ..
الحكومة الإلكترونية..
العمالة الأجنبية في..
الديموقراطية الخليجي..
الديمقراطية الكويتية..
مصطفى النحاس ودوره ف..
الأمم المتحدة والتدخ..
الاسلاموفبيا جماعات..
تاريخ أفغانستان وتطو..
الثورة التشيكية وتجر..
قوة المستضعفين
اشهر قضايا الاغتيالا..
المرأة والربيع العرب..
التجربة البرازيلية ق..
اسرائيل في حوض النيل
أوربيانا - مختصر تار..
يوميات دولة انتقالية
تجربة جنوب افريقيا -..
التجربة الماليزية -..
المياة العربية وحروب..
سياسة ايران تجاة دول..
التجربه التشيلية .....
التجربه الاندونسيه ...
التجارة الخارجيه الي..
الدور البرلمانى للمر..
محنه الدستور ... وإش..
الحروب بالوكالة - اد..
العلاقات السعوديه ال..
هاربون من الموت : ال..
كيفية صناعة التطرف ؟..
الفساد والإصلاح : ال..
العلاقات الأمريكية ا..
التجربة الصينية الما..
دينى ودين الناس .. ا..
الأرض المحرمة - كوري..
القضية الكردية : إشك..
العلاقات الإيرانية ا..
السياسة الخارجية الت..
العلاقات الإيرانية ا..
القومية والأمة: مدخل..
التجربة الالمانية ....
التجربة الإماراتية :..
بوكو حرام : من الجما..
التجربة الهندية : أك..
ماذا تعرف عن البركست..
العلاقات اليمنية الخ..
أمريكا وحركات الإسلا..
المشروع الصهيوني: ال..
وحدتنا الوطنية بين ث..
ليبيا ما بعد القذافي..
النظام الانتخابي ....
ضد الانتخابات .. دفا..
التجربة الكندية .. ب..
التجربة الإيرانية....
التجربة الأرجنتينية..
التجربة الباكستانية..
الثورة والحرب .. تشك..
الأقليات في أثيوبيا..
العلاقات السورية الت..
العلاقات الصينية الأ..
كتابات هيكل .. بين ا..
التعليم الالالكتروني..
البرنامج النووي الاي..
لماذا تنتفض الشعوب ؟..
العنف المقدس.. النفو..
قضايا الخيانة والجاس..
مدخل الي القرن الافر..
إخوان مصر .. بين الص..
أمريكا والربيع العرب..
العلاقات المصرية الا..
العلاقات بين الكوريت..
سد النهضة الإثيوبي ...
آخر أيام البشير .. ا..
التجربة.. تفاعلات ال..
عزيزي النفط.. ماذا ف..
ملوك النفط .. كيف قل..
الشغف العربي
المنافسة على القمة و..
اليمن والقاعدة.. الح..
في عين العاصفة
مصدق والصراع على الس..
مصدق والصراع على الس..
الفكر السياسي للأحزا..
الثورات العربية.. سي..
التمرد السوري
قيامة شعب .. قراءة أ..
في أصول لبنان الطائف..
```

Comment: I use requests.Session() to handle cookie by requests itself.

Comment: I also use css selector with bs4 . In last step, you can select each htlm element from the visiting url meaning  from get url .